# Conditional formatting a date range

Tags: formatting, date-range

I am trying to conditional format in SSRS.
in my report I have a planned start field and an actual start field.
I want the actual start field to change to red if the actual start date is more than an hour or less than an hour of the planned start date.
So if the planned start date is 25/07/2021 21:00 but the actual start date is 25/07/2021 22:00 then I want the actual start date to turn red.
Also if the planned start date is 25/07/2021 21:00 but the actual start date is 25/07/2021 20:00 then I want the actual start date to turn red.
can this be done?

This is what I have tried so far

=iif(DateDiff("H", Fields!ACTUAL_START_DATE.Value, Fields!PLANNED_START_DATE.Value) >= 1, "red", "black")

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to handle this. Your method is fine, just need to add ABS() to your expression and it should work.

```
=iif(ABS(DateDiff("H", Parameters!actualstart.Value, Parameters!plannedstart.Value)) >= 1, "red", "black")
```